# What are the limits on interacting with cross domain iframe content through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am building an application which will be hosted on my domain and viewed from another domain. The way the application works, it is easiest to simply embed it from my website through an iframe. However, I need to interact with some of the application elements on the client side through JavaScript.

I know there are limits as to what can and cannot be accessed through JavaScript but could someone please clarify the list of what is and is not doable. I can not find this online for the life of me.

Could someone clarify the same origin policy or link to a clear explanation of what is allowed.

Also, so that it is not suggested, same domain is not possible due to issues with server and application compatibility.

Comment: Everything you'll ever need to know about [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: Not exactly everything.  You should also read the XHR spec, which covers additional CORS elements.